# Low-voltage splices behind Drywall without junction box access?

Tags: low-voltage, catv, splices

For 120VAC, I know that 'splices' in NM/Romex are **not** allowed behind drywall: there must be a junction box to inspect the splice.

For low-voltage, such as CATV, how big of a deal is it?

The previous owner left my house with a CATV splice (pictured below), and we're about to add drywall to this ceiling.

Do I need to remove this CATV (RG6 Quad Shield) cable and re-run it as a continuous run with NO splice?  (Or add a junction box for access; but I don't want to do this).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low-voltage stuff isn't regulated in that way. Just know that you lose signal quality with a splicer like that, so some means of eliminating it later is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly that is fine I do low voltage fire alarm and that has to be in a junction but your talking about cable wire here that is fine but yes you will lose quality with that splice

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider that a splice.  It's a connectorized connection.  If the cable ends are properly installed, with the shield maintained 360 deg around the cable/connector interface, and a good quality female adapter used, that connection is as good as the cable it connects to.

Here the other extreme of what NOT to do for a cable connection.  This one was actually buried in the ground.

[image]

No matter what, I would note where that connection is (take a picture, measure from a wall, etc) so that if troubleshooting is needed in the future, you have an idea where that junction is.